# Lightbox evolution preventing the window from scrolling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, lightbox

I hope someone might be able to help me with this. I am currently using the `lightbox evolution` plugin to display some nice lightboxes on my page.

I noticed that it allows the user to continue to scroll up and down the page if the modal / lightbox is shown.

I have added the following code:

```
$('a.light-box').lightbox({
    'onOpen'  : function() {$('html, body').css({'overflow': 'hidden','height': '100%'});},
    'onClose' : function() {$('html, body').css({'overflow': 'auto','height': 'auto'});}
});
```

It prevents the scrolling from happening, but if I launch a link half way down the page then it automatically tries to scroll to the top of the page which kinda defeats the purposes of the scrolling.

Is there any other css properties that I could use to prevent it from scrolling to the top of the page ?

thanks in advance

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` while launching your link??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your script:

```
$('a.light-box').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```